# Correctly type check reducer with Flow

Tags: typescript, redux, flowtype

I try to integrate Flow with a Redux codebase.
I'm pretty new to Flow but I already have played with TypeScript a little.

I want to be able to catch wrong action type inside the reducer.

```
type Action = 
  | { type: 'sample' }
  | { type: 'django' }  
  ;

type State = {
  content: string,
};

const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => {
  switch (action.type) {
    // OK
    case 'sample':
      return { content: '' };

    // Should raise a type error, because the action type 
    // will never be equal to "error" 
    case 'error':
      return { content: '' };

    default:
      return { content: '' };
  }
};
```

[Exemple in Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHZQLxQFBSgHygG8pRIAuKAcgGcBDAWzABsIqoBfXA408CSlQAmAKzqoA5snYc83ANzZsZaAGVgdYNCxFucNFtTBKNYACdEkgDTYOi7PtSmoZiEICucCGcxQAFKaaAlDqQVZQdAgoqJTwSGgAlJShWpgAfMTcNADuiMBwABb+kfGoAHQqCZl4eAD0tSEFyO7MQi50iDTQdHyQUN5myGbhAEYQcHTuXaQF3VFovdDcdQ25zMxQqBAAbt5QY-0Aju50G8DIUABEA0OXODVQE9NUN2ZU5Ms1rsDuZugkjkMxmoMkUDyEEAAZpNmMZPnhvr9-o8DBAjIJQdwuHYgA)
[Exemple in TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Action%20%3D%20%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20%7B%20type%3A%20'sample'%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20%7B%20type%3A%20'django'%20%7D%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20State%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20content%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20reducer%20%3D%20(state%3A%20State%2C%20action%3A%20Action)%3A%20State%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20switch%20(action.type)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20'error'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20content%3A%20''%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20default%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20content%3A%20''%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B)

I don't understand why Flow don't catch the error in this case.
Flow infer the `type` property as a `string` but I set explicitly the type to be `'sample' | 'django'`.

Did I miss something ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug in flow, but you can enforce a strict verification as follows:

```
type ActionType = 'sample' | 'django'
type Action = {type: ActionType}

type State = {
  content: string,
};

const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => {
  const type:ActionType = action.type;
  switch (type) {
    // Should raise a type error, because the action type 
    // will never be equal to "error" 
    case 'error':
      return { content: '' };
    default:
      return { content: '' };
  }
};
```

This gives:

```
13:     case 'error':
             ^ string literal `error`. This type is incompatible with
9:   const type:ActionType = action.type;
                ^ string enum
```

Comment: indeed a bug / work in progress - see https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2399